# Time Distributed Convolutional Layers in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, keras

In Keras, there is a time distributed wrapper that applies a layer to every temporal slice of an input. Is there a similar wrapper that is available in Tensorflow? Or how do I build time distributed layers in Tensorflow?

Answer (score 3):

You could try a basic reshape:

- Take a tensor of shape `(?, timeSteps, ...other_dimensions...)`
- Reshape it to `(-1,  ...other_dimensions...)`
- Apply the layer/operation
- Reshape it back to `(-1, timeSteps, ...other_dimensions...)`

Answer (score 0):

Keras layers are now supported in recent versions of tensor flow. You can use `tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed` to accomplish your task.