# How to use GRUCell when defining custom keras layer with additional weights?

Tags: keras, keras-layer

I am defining a custom keras word embedding layer that uses both a cnn and rnn, I modified the code from GRU to use a GRUCell and some self defined weights for the CNN filters. Importantly, the filter weights are defined in the build method for the layer while the GRUCell weights are defined by calling the cell build method. For some reason this causes the weights for only one of them to be registered, depending on whether I inherit from RNN or Layer. If I inherit from RNN it registers the weights for the RNN only, if I inherit from layer it registers the weights for the CNN only. By register I mean when I use the layer and check the number of parameters, they correspond only to those for the CNN and RNN respectively. I'm assuming that the other sets of weights do not get trained as training doesn't work. I would like some ideas about what is wrong with my code, do I have to define the weights for the RNN inside the build method for the layer?

```
from keras.layers.recurrent import RNN, GRUCell
import keras.backend as K
class cnn_lstm_layer(RNN):
def __init__(self, num_vocab, embed_dim, units=10):
    self.num_vocab = num_vocab
    self.embed_dim = embed_dim
    self.units = units
    cell = GRUCell(units)
    super().__init__(cell)

def build(self, input_shape):

    f2_count = 3
    f3_count = 4
    f4_count = 5

    self.embeddings = self.add_weight(
        shape=[self.num_vocab, self.embed_dim],
        initializer='glorot_uniform',
        name='char_embeddings')
    self.kernel2 = self.add_weight(
        shape=[2, self.embed_dim, 1, f2_count],
        initializer='glorot_uniform',
        name='f2')
    self.kernel3 = self.add_weight(
        shape=[3, self.embed_dim, 1, f3_count],
        initializer='glorot_uniform',
        name='f3')
    self.kernel4 = self.add_weight(
        shape=[4, self.embed_dim, 1, f4_count],
        initializer='glorot_uniform',
        name='f4')
    self.conv_output_len = f2_count + f3_count + f4_count

    step_input_shape = [None, self.conv_output_len]
    self.cell.build(step_input_shape)

    self.built = True

def call(self, inputs):
    '''
    uses the following reshaping trick
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51091544/time-distributed-convolutional-layers-in-tensorflow
    '''
    inputs = K.cast(inputs, tf.int32)
    encoded = K.gather(self.embeddings, inputs)
    #        encoded = K.print_tensor(encoded, message = 'encoded: ')
    #        encoded = K.tf.Print(encoded, data = [encoded],message='encoded: ',summarize = 1000)
    encoded = K.expand_dims(encoded, -1)
    input_shape = K.int_shape(encoded)
    _, s_words, s_char, s_embed_dim, _ = input_shape
    encoded = K.reshape(encoded, (-1, s_char, s_embed_dim, 1))
    paddings2 = [[0, 0], [1, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]
    paddings3 = [[0, 0], [2, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]
    paddings4 = [[0, 0], [3, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]

    c2 = K.conv2d(tf.pad(encoded, paddings2),
                  self.kernel2,
                  data_format='channels_last',
                  padding='valid')  # shape = (?,19,1,3)
    c3 = K.conv2d(tf.pad(encoded, paddings3),
                  self.kernel3,
                  data_format='channels_last',
                  padding='valid')
    c4 = K.conv2d(tf.pad(encoded, paddings4),
                  self.kernel4,
                  data_format='channels_last',
                  padding='valid')
    c = K.concatenate([c2, c3, c4], axis=3)  # shape = (?,19,1,12)
    c = K.squeeze(c, 2)  # shape = (?,19,12)


    initial_state = self.get_initial_state(c)
    last_output, outputs, states = K.rnn(self.cell.call,
                                            c,
                                            initial_state)
    output = last_output

    output = K.reshape(output,(-1,s_words,self.units))
    return output


def get_initial_state(self, inputs):
    # build an all-zero tensor of shape (samples, output_dim)
    initial_state = K.zeros_like(inputs)  # (samples, timesteps, input_dim)
    initial_state = K.sum(initial_state, axis=(1, 2))  # (samples,)
    initial_state = K.expand_dims(initial_state)  # (samples, 1)
    if hasattr(self.cell.state_size, '__len__'):
        return [K.tile(initial_state, [1, dim])
                for dim in self.cell.state_size]
    else:
        return [K.tile(initial_state, [1, self.cell.state_size])]



def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
    batch_size, s_words, s_char = input_shape
    output_shape = (batch_size, s_words,self.units)
    return output_shape
```

Answer (score 0):

The heart of the problem lies in the trainable_weights method. In the RNN class this is defined as

```
def trainable_weights(self):
    if not self.trainable:
        return []
    if isinstance(self.cell, Layer):
        return self.cell.trainable_weights
    return []
```

while in the Layer class this is defined as

```
def trainable_weights(self):
    trainable = getattr(self, 'trainable', True)
    if trainable:
        return self._trainable_weights
    else:
        return []
```

This is the reason why when inheriting from RNN and Layer give weights from RNN or CNN only. The solution then is to rewrite trainable_weights to take into account both weights defined in the build method outside and weights defined in the cell build method. i.e.

```
@property
def trainable_weights(self):
    return self._trainable_weights + self.cell.trainable_weights
```